# Custom Permalink Structure Using Custom Taxonomy Name, Custom Taxonomy Term, and Default Post Name (Not CPT)

Tags: wordpress

I am building a site that will not use pages at all, and instead use posts (old school WP usage here).  I will not be using the built-in 'categories', however, and instead will use one of four custom taxonomies.  Again, these custom taxonomies will be attached to the default posts, not a custom post type.  The problem I am running into is the permalink structure.  I want my post permalink to include the first taxonomy term assigned to it, plus the name of the taxonomy.  For example:

I have a custom taxonomy called 'academics', with a term of 'education'.  If a post is categorized as 'education', the URL to that post should be '/academics/education/postname/'.

Even if this post is categorized with multiple custom taxonomy terms, I only want the first one found to show in the URL.

Here is how I set up the taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy( 'academics', 'post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Academics' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Academics' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Academics' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Academics' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Academics' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Academics' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Academics' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Academics' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Academics Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Academics With Commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or Remove Academics' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose From the Most Used Academics' )
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => false,
    'meta_box_cb' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true
) );
```

I then have my permalink structure (in the admin area) set up like this:

```
/%custom_category%/%postname%/
```

Then I have two functions... this first one replaces `%custom_category%` with the first term from the first custom taxonomy associated with the post:

```
/**
 * replace the '%custom_category%' tag with the first
 * term slug found for the post
 *
 * @wp-hook post_link
 * @param string $permalink
 * @param WP_Post $post
 * @return string
 */
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_taxonomy_permalink', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_taxonomy_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_taxonomy_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%custom_category%' ) === false ) {
        return $permalink;
    }
    // Get post
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return $permalink;
    }
    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, array(
        'academics',
        'art-performance',
        'on-campus-announcements',
        'student-life-events'
    ) );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) {
        $taxonomy = $terms[0]->taxonomy . '/';
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    } else {
        $taxonomy = '';
        $taxonomy_slug = '';
    }
    return str_replace('%custom_category%', $taxonomy . $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

All of the above works great and the permalink structure on the front end matches exactly what I want... however every post comes back as a 404.  So I assumed I needed to created custom rewrites.  So I have another function which should be adding rewrite rules:

```
    // Function to create custom rewrite rules
    function custom_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
        $newRules  = array();
        $newRules['academics/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?academics=$matches[1]';
        $newRules['academics/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]';
        return array_merge( $newRules, $rules );
    }
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
```

This is where I am guessing things have gone wrong as I am not too familiar with custom rewrites.  And currently the function is only handling the 'academics' custom taxonomy because I figured if I got this one working, I could use the same logic for the rest of them.

Anyone have any ideas as to why my permalinks won't work?  Every time I change the rewrites, I do visit the permalinks settings page to flush the rules.  I am also using the old [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin to see my rules taking effect, so I know they are there... they are just not working.